# How to access methods of ancestor class when intermediate parent class overrides it?

Tags: java

abstract class Parent {
    int i = 9;

```
void display() {
    System.out.println("base");
}
```

}

class Child extends Parent {
    int i = 8;

```
public void display() {

    System.out.println("derived");
}
```

}

public class A {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Parent a1 = new Child();
    a1.display(); // calls child class method
    System.out.println(a1.i);// calls parent class member

}
```

}

Comment: when i run this code display method of derived class is being called

Comment: That's the normal behavior since the object is a `Child` even if the variable is declared as `Parent`. Again, what's your real specific question?

Comment: Why is `A` extending `Child`? I see no reason for that, as none of the inherited properties are used.

Comment: Sigh... What abstract class are we talking about?  What the heck is the variable "i" doing in there?  Why, if he wants to call Parent.display(), did he create a Child?  Why is someone editing this post without fixing the obvious spelling issues?  Lots of good questions here.

Comment: ok even if i remove  A extending child i am unable to get get method of Parent class

Comment: @user2677261 Yes, it has nothing to do with your problem, but it still complicates your code for no reason.

Comment: Sorry, @user2677261, I think the point is..  Child derived from Parent and overrode the display method...  if you want to call Parent's display method, create a PARENT.  At the A class level, it doesn't even know there IS a Parent.display anymore.  If, in Child.display, you want to call Parent.display, do that with super.display.

Comment: is your `Parent` class is abstract .? then you should declare it...

Comment: @BillJames OP wants to call the `display()` method of the `Parent` class on a `Child`, which overrides it. This is not possible in Java.

Comment: @Pietu1998  I can get that, but nowhere in his question does he seem to SAY that.  And wth is "abstract" about any of this?  And "overriding property"?  Heck with it, I'm changing the title.

Comment: There, IF that's the real question, then you have several answers below now... all of them basically the same... you can't do that.

Comment: @BillJames my answer is not the same as others.

Comment: what if Parent is a abstract class

Comment: @user2677261 then you can't call `new Parent` and the `Parent` class can have `abstract` methods with no definition.

Comment: I can even have methods in abstract class

Comment: @user2677261 Edit your question to add more info directly in the question so others don't need to read all comments.

Comment: suppose the class which is extending the abstract class is overriding the method of abstract class which is not abstract one then how to access the method of abstract class across different classes

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot access `Parent` class  `display()` method directly without creating an object of it**.
But you can access it from you child class.like this

```
 class Child extends Parent {
   int i = 8;
   public void display() {
      super.display();
      System.out.println("derived");
   }
 }
```

According to java docs [Accessing Superclass Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

> If your method overrides one of its superclass's methods, you can invoke the overridden method through the use of the keyword super. You can also use super to refer to a hidden field (although hiding fields is discouraged).

Comment: Wether the base cklass is abstract doesn't matter. You can of course invoke base class methods from an abstract class, once you have an object. You just can't instantiate an abstract class.

Comment: This doesn't help in OP's question, which was if `display()` was overridden without the `super.display()` call. Also if you override a method with just `super.method()` the you don't have to override it at all.

Answer (score 1):

> when i run this code display method of derived class is being called

Looks like you have programmed in other programming languages like C++ or C# where you must specify the method as `virtual` in order to use the subclass method. In Java, all the methods except `private`, `final` and `static` are virtual.

Knowing this, since `Child` class already overrides `display` method from `Parent` class, when you do this:

```
Parent a1 = new Child();
a1.display();
```

`a1.display` will execute the `display` method of the actual object reference class, in this case, `Child#display`.

In order to *fix* the code, change the initialization of `a1` to be a new `Parent`:

```
Parent a1 = new Parent();
a1.display();
```

More info:

- [Can you write virtual functions / methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4547453/1065197)

---

After your edit, now you face the problem when printing `a1` in the console, probably printing `9` instead of `8`. What you're doing here is **hiding the field**. Fields **do not** get overridden, so the value of the `i` variable will depend on the actual class type declared for the variable. Since you have declared `a1` as `Parent`, then `a1.i` will take the value of `Parent#i`.

In order to *fix* this code, change the `a1` variable type to `Child`:

```
Child a1 = new Child();
System.out.println(a1.i);
a1.display();
```

Or a even better solution: **NEVER** try to *override* a field, and what's worse, don't try to access to class fields from other classes directly, instead use the respective **getters** and **setters**.

More info:

- [Hiding fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html)

---

> How to access methods of ancestor class when intermediate parent class overrides it?

Assuming this is your real question, then the answer is simple: you can't.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right you are trying to invoke the PARENTS display method using CHILD instance.

With **just** the derived class object there's **NO** way to instruct the compiler to make the non-virtual call to the base-class version.

Answer (score 0):

You just cannot. If you want the code in parent class to be executed then you either have to create a parent class (note: `Parent` is not abstract class) or you have to provide call to `super.someMethod()` in one of the methods of the child. For example:

```
public void display() {
        super.display();
        System.out.println("derived");
    }
```

Comment: what if a Parent class is a abstract one

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to ask is why the variables of parent class is displayed and method of child class.

Firstly, overriding is not applied to variables,it is applied on methods. Whatever class the reference belongs to, that variable will be displayed straight away.In your code,

```
    Parent a1 = new Child();  
    System.out.println(a1.i);
```

Here a1 is a reference to Parent class, so variable of Parent class is displayed.

In case of methods, it is decided at run time which version of methods would be called. That method is called whose object is created, here object of Child class is crated `Parent a1 =new Child();` . See the part **new Child()** and hence the Child class method. But remember, this method should be present in the class that the reference belongs. For example

```
   Class Parent
    {
    }

   Class Child extends Parent
    { 
      public void display() 
        {
          System.out.println("derived");
        }
      public static void main (String []args)
        {
         Parent a1 = new Child();
         a1.display();    //Error  
        }  
      }
```

To call the base class method in your original example, use super as others have mentioned. Or simply create an object of parent class

```
Parent o = new Parent();
o.display();              //prints base
```