# Referencing a variable declared in abstract class from inherited class

Tags: java, c#, oop, inheritance

I'm currently reading a book on design patterns which is written towards java, but would like to code examples in both Java and C#. Right now I'm trying to implement the strategy pattern in C#, and while I've found a lot of examples online, my current problem is something that I want to figure out the most.

In the Java example I have an abstract class and then a class that extends that abstract class. In the abstract class I declare, but don't instantiate, variables of an interface, which are then instantiated in the extended class.

Interface:

```
public interface MathStuff{
    public void add();
}
```

Abstract:

```
public abstract class Math{
    MathStuff mathStuff;

    public Math(){}

    public void addStuff(){
        mathStuff.add();
    }
}
```

Extended Class:

```
public class DoStuffWithMath extends Math{
    public DoStuffWithMath(){
        mathStuff = new RandomClass();
    }
}
```

Now I would really like to replicate this in C#. The C# code is essentially the same. I have an interface, an abstract class, and a class that I assume is extending the abstract class. I am not as familiar with C#. That class looks like this.

```
class DoStuffWithMath : Math{
    public DoStuffWithMath(){
        mathStuff = new RandomClass();
    }
}
```

The problem with the C# code is where i try to say "mathStuff = new RandomClass()". Any help or reading material would be appreciate.

Comment: If you declare an instance member without an access modifier in C#, it is considered `private`. You'll need something like `protected`.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295224/what-are-major-differences-between-c-sharp-and-java and links. There are some differences between Java and C# (virtual, default access specifiers,...) that makes copy-pasted Java code not to work the same in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly adding `protected` would fix the issue (to override default `private` access):

```
public abstract class Math{
    protected MathStuff mathStuff;

    public Math(){}

    public void addStuff(){
        mathStuff.add();
    }
}
```

Note that depending on your needs either passing `mathStuff` as constructor of base class or using property instead of field would be better solution.